# React-Native: Adding react-navigation makes code rebuild constantly

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I added react-navigation to my app. Just to test I used the exact code from the [documents](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation).

After getting the imports right, every 20-30 seconds and sometimes longer, the app rebuilds and refreshes.

Important note is that beforehand this was not an issue. Things worked just fine beforehand.

I'm new to react-native, so any help however basic, would be great.

Comment: When you say rebuild, do you mean its re-rendering or re-compiling the App?

Comment: The terminal shows a `Finished building JavaScript bundle in 24ms` which in turn re-renders the app.

Comment: What is your build environment? This is being triggered from outside the app itself

Answer (score 0):

Many people have this issue when their project is located in a cloud storage folder such as Dropbox. I am encountering this issue with no cloud storage.

My solution to a constant rebuild was to 'rm -rf node_modules' and 'npm install' afresh. My app now performs correctly.